# Как использовать значение вычисленной колонки для вычисления другой колонки в запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle, alias, aggregate

Нужно узнать отношение двух вычисленных полей. Почему не получится написать запрос в таком виде?

```
select manager_id, 
    sum(sale_amount) over (partition by manager_id, trunc(sale_date, 'MM'))
        sale_current_month, 
    sum(sale_amount) over (partition by manager_id order by trunc(sale_date, 'MM'
        ) RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' month preceding) 
        sale_previous_month, 
    sale_current_month/sale_previous_month 
from fact_sale;
```

Могу создать новое представление или продублировать код, но можно как нибудь проще решить эту проблему?

Comment: *можно как нибудь проще решить эту проблему?* Отож... для того и CTE (WITH clause).

Comment: @Akina, зачем CTE если обычный подзапрос (SELECT FROM SELECT) читается гораздо легче?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Насчёт "читается гораздо легче" - однозначно не соглашусь. Когда логические подзадачи решаются отдельно - логика видна гораздо лучше, чем когда они перемешаны. Другой вопрос - производительность (впрочем, у Оракла с CTE в этом плане гораздо лучше, чем у, скажем, старого постгресса), если это ускоряет - да, после отладки можно код перенести из CTE в секцию FROM. Но я лично в подобных случаях исходный, до переноса, текст сохраняю комментарием.

Comment: @Akina, "получить C=A/B, где A=…, B=…" vs "Используя A=… и B=…, получить С=A/B". Второе уж как-то сильно императивщиной отдает, ИМХО

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Простите, а необходимость отдельного CTE при использовании оконных функций Вас тоже коробит? Мне, например, гораздо труднее согласиться именно с разрешением использования в выражении выходного набора алиасов полей этого набора. Ибо это однозначно потребует серьёзных изменений в исполнении запроса - например, в документировании порядка выполнения выражений в выходном наборе. Более того, в такой возможности заложена потенциальная неоднозначность: `SELECT a AS b, b AS a, b/a AS c` - и сиди, разбирайся, что получишь в сухом остатке, да с учётом особенностей SQL (сравни с UPDATE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> почему не получится написать запрос в таком виде?

Таков стандарт SQL касательно видимости алиасов. Из офф. док. [select_list >> c_alias](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

> Specify an alias for the column expression. [ ... ]
> The alias can be used in the *order_by_clause* **but not other clauses in the query**.

Алиас выражения для колонки в запросе может быть использован только в `ORDER BY`, больше нигде, включая текущий лист значений запроса SELECT.

> Могу создать новое представление или продублировать код, но можно как нибудь проще решить эту проблему?

Нет, третьего не дано. В воспроизводимом примере ниже оба варианта, которые возвращают идентичный результат. Какой из них проще, решайте сами:

```sql
with sales (id, mgrid, amount) as (
    select rownum, mod (rownum, 3)+1, rownum*10 
    from xmlTable ('1 to 9')
)
select mgrid, total, totalByMgr, trunc (totalByMgr / total * 100) prcByMgr
from (
    select
        mgrid, 
        sum (amount) over () total,
        sum (amount) over (partition by mgrid) totalByMgr
    from sales
)
union all
select 
    mgrid, 
    sum (amount) over () total,
    sum (amount) over (partition by mgrid) totalByMgr,
    trunc (sum (amount) over (partition by mgrid) / sum (amount) over () * 100) prcByMgr
from sales;
```